# Successfully redeeming promo code for in-app purchase in IOS app store is not triggering purchaseUpdatedListener in RNIAP

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, promotion-code, react-native-iap

In Testflight app on iphone, on entering promo code for in-app purchase, I am getting a success message from the app store but purchaseUpdateListener is not being triggered. Tested by adding alerts within purchaseUpdateListener.

I am using the same purchase flow for in-app purchases and that is working fine.

Expected Behavior

Trigger Promo Code redemption using this URL(itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=PROMO_CODE') on click of button within app for an in-app purchase.
Click Redeem.
Success message shown in app store.
purchaseUpdatedListener receives an event and receipt.

Actual Behavior

Trigger Promo Code redemption using this URL(itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=PROMO_CODE') on click of button within app for an in-app purchase.
Click Redeem.
Success message shown in app store.
purchaseUpdatedListener receives NO event.

Environment:

react-native-iap:12.10.5
react-native:0.71.8
Platforms (iOS, Android, emulator, simulator, device): Testflight app on IOS real device

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this as well on my paywall. If someone submits a promo code through apples website, the device is unaware of it when they are redirected back to my app.

The only fix I can think of is to add a listener that gets triggered by your app going from background to foreground (https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate). Inside that listener you can check if someone has made the purchase.

This seems a bit hacky since it would get called anytime the app goes from background to foreground. Also open to hearing other solutions!!